# Reorder elements in a Java stream

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have a stream of objects and would like to implement a rule that ensures that the first item in the stream doesn’t meet a particular criteria (eg is not an odd number). I don’t want to just discard those items though, I just want to make sure they are not first in the list.

How do I implement something like this with a Java Stream?

Comment: i don't think this is quite a problem definition. say... given [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] what do you want. [2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7] or [2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8] or something else

Comment: You might want to consider using a for loop if the indexes matter that much

Comment: @mavriksc the second list (2,1,3,4...)

Comment: check answers and pls updoot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator to sort your stream elements. Also, you can create comparator with a few rules by calling method `firstComparator.thenComparing(secondComparator)`. See example. For input, we have numbers: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. For output, we will have: `[2, 4, 8, 10, 3, 9, 5, 7]`. First, we put even numbers. Then we put numbers divisible by three. And then we put other numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10));

    Comparator<Integer> firstComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 == 0 || o1 % 2 != 0 && o2 % 2 != 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 % 2 == 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    };

    Comparator<Integer> secondComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if (o1 % 3 == 0 && o2 % 3 == 0 || o1 % 3 != 0 && o2 % 3 != 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 % 3 == 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    };

    List<Integer> sortedList = sourceList
            .stream()
            .sorted(firstComparator.thenComparing(secondComparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(sortedList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is a great solution. but it does what you want. 
`things` is a List  and `getNum()` accesses the feature  you want to see if is even.

`things.add(0,things.remove(things.indexOf(things.stream().filter(t->t.getNum()%2==0).findFirst().orElse(things.get(0)))));`

basically filters the list and finds the first even property element and removes it by index which returns the element and then inserts that at the head of the list.